Firebase AuthSettings - how to set the properties?
According to the documentation for AuthSettings: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/authsettings
We have the following property in AuthSettings interface: forceRecaptchaFlowForTesting
How can it be modified? I've tried a simple setting to true, like this:
    auth().settings.forceRecaptchaFlowForTesting = true;

But it always returns the error about the cyclical JSON structure ...
